# Dataflow SQL - unsupported column type NUMERIC

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

I'm trying to set up a Dataflow-SQL job to run a query in BigQUery and publish the results to a PubSub topic. I'm not using a Dataflow template, I'm using the GCP's Dataflow SQL UI to write a query and configure the output - i.e. PubSub Topic.

The table I'm querying contains String, Date, Timestamp, and Numeric types.

Even if I don't select the column with 'Numeric' data type, I still get a validation error in the editor - unsupported column type NUMERIC.

Is there a way to get around this in Dataflow SQL? Or the source table just can't have columns of Numeric Type?

Answer (score 2):

[Numeric types](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/sql/data-types#numeric-types) in Dataflow SQL are INT64 and FLOAT64 (8 bytes) but not NUMERIC (16 bytes).

I reproduced your issue on my end and it certainly looks like the table cannot be loaded in the first place, even if you are not selecting the NUMERIC column.